# What is SDB's full name in Jena

Tags: jena

I know Jena SDB has been end of life since Dec 2020.
Nevertheless, I wonder what SDB stands for.
Is is Statement Data Base or Semantic Data Base?
Even referring to Jena's homepage, there was no answer to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't stand for anything. It is "SDB".

The previous system was "RDB".
The successor is "TDB".

Vaguely and *not formally*:
RDF DataBase
SPARQL DataBase
Tuple DataBase

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect that.
Thank you.